# How to bind controls across two fxml from the Main controller

Tags: javafx-2

I Need to bind controls from different fxml in the main controller.
I have 3 fxml files named MainView.fxml, ChildView1.fxml and ChildView2.fxml.

**MainView.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="view" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="binding.example2.MainViewController">
<children>
<VBox prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="500.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
  <children>
    <fx:include fx:id="child1" source="ChildView1.fxml" />
    <fx:include fx:id="child2" source="ChildView2.fxml" />
  </children>
</VBox>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**ChildView1.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="view" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="464.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="binding.example2.ChildView1Controller">
<children>
<HBox layoutX="32.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0">
 <children>
    <Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="37.0" text="Button1" />
    <Button fx:id="button2" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="37.0" text="Button2" />
  </children>
</HBox>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**ChildView2.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="view" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="568.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="binding.example2.ChildView2Controller">
 <children>
   <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="568.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**MainController.java**

```
package binding.example2;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;        
public class MainViewController {
@FXML
private Parent view;
@FXML
private AnchorPane child1;
@FXML
private AnchorPane child2;
@FXML
private ChildView1Controller childView1Controller;
@FXML
private ChildView2Controller childView2Controller; 
@FXML
 void initialize() {
      System.out.println("MainViewController.initialize()");
   // childView1Controller.getButton1() ;
 }

public Parent getView() {
     return view;
  }

}
```

**ChildView1Controller.java**

```
package binding.example2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;


public class ChildView1Controller {

@FXML private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML private URL location;

@FXML private Button button1;

@FXML private Button button2;

@FXML private Node view;


@FXML
void initialize() {
    System.out.println("ChildView1Controller.initialize()");

    button1.setDisable(true);

}

 public Node getView()
 {
    return view;
 }

 public Button getButton1(){
    return button1; 
 }

}
```

**ChildView2Controller.java**

```
package binding.example2;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


public class ChildView2Controller {

@FXML private Node view;

@FXML private TableView<Person> tableView;

ObservableList<Person> data ;

public Node getView(){
    return view ;
   }

 @FXML
 void initialize() {
    System.out.println("ChildView2Controller.initialize()");

    //populateTable();
 }

public TableView<Person> getTableView(){
    return tableView ;
}   
 }
```

By default, button1 is disabled from ChildView1Controller.

I want to enable it when a table row in my other view (ChildView2.fxml) is selected. Again disable it when the table row is deselected. Basically i want to bind the button and table so that button is enabled when a table row is selected.
Please help me with the MainViewController code to bind the button and the table row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject the controllers of the included fxml on the `MainViewController` controller, as indicated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).

Then, you can perform the desired bindings at `MainViewController`'s initialize method. Considering that the child controllers expose the `Button` and the `TableView` with `getter` methods, the `MainViewController` could be:

```
public class MainViewController {
    @FXML
    private ChildView1Controller childView1Controller;
    @FXML
    private ChildView2Controller childView2Controller;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        childView1Controller.getButton1().visibleProperty().bind(
            childView2Controller.getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNotNull());
    }
}
```

To correctly inject these child controllers, it is needed to change the include elements at **MainView.fxml**, updating their `fx:id` attribute:

```
<fx:include fx:id="childView1" source="ChildView1.fxml" />
<fx:include fx:id="childView2" source="ChildView2.fxml" />
```

Relevant comment from @Dil:

*The requirement is that if the fx:id of your included resource is "xxx", the variable name for the corresponding controller is xxxController (so details -> detailsController)*

Comment: @Crferreira Thanks for your inputs. I have added my Controller classes as well. I am not sure how to inject the childView controller in the MainViewConroller. I am not able to access childView1Controller or childView2Controller from MainViewController. Can you please check where/what is wrong with my code ? If i try to access childView1Controller, it throws exception.

Comment: @Crferreira thats it. it works. I was unaware of the fact that **"The requirement is that if the fx:id of your included resource is "xxx", the variable name for the corresponding controller is xxxController (so details -> detailsController)"**