# JavaFX - reach the main controller from the sub controller

Tags: java, javafx

On [this page from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm) is explained how to inject a sub controller in the main controller:

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MainController"> 
...
    <fx:include fx:id="dialog" source="dialog.fxml"/>
...
</VBox>

public class MainController extends Controller { 
    @FXML private Window dialog;
    @FXML private DialogController dialogController;

    ...
```

Now, I wanted to know, how to reach the `MainController` instance out of the sub controller (in this case the `DialogController`).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Set it manually: dialogController.setMainController(this);

Comment: set manually or make MainController a Singleton.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! But there are no build-in solution like injection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind controls across two fxml from the Main controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435384/how-to-bind-controls-across-two-fxml-from-the-main-controller)

Comment: No, it isn't, because I want to know how to reach the main controller out of the sub controller instance.

Comment: Don't do it. It adds unnecessary coupling between the two controllers, and breaks encapsulation. Instead, expose observable state from the `DialogController` and observe it in the `MainController`.

Comment: @Tobi you can't make a controller a singleton. (How would that work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not doing this. If your `DialogController` has a dependency on your `MainController`, then it can't be used independently of the `MainController`, which adds unnecessary coupling between the two (i.e. it breaks encapsulation).

You probably only want something to happen in the `MainController` when some state in the `DialogController` changes. So you should expose that state as an observable property in `DialogController` and observe it from the main controller:

```
public class DialogController {

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Person> selectedPerson = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Person> selectedPersonProperty() {
        return selectedPerson.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final Person getSelectedPerson() {
        return selectedPersonProperty().get();
    }

    @FXML
    private Button okButton ;

    public void initialize() {
        okButton.setOnAction(selectedPerson.set(new Person(...)));
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class MainController extends Controller { 
    @FXML private Window dialog;
    @FXML private DialogController dialogController;

    public void initialize() {
        dialogController.selectedPersonProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            // ... whatever you need to do here with new data when OK is pressed in dialog...
        });
    }
}
```

If you really want to access the `MainController` from the `DialogController`, then you can do so as suggested in the comments, by "manually" injecting the `MainController` into the `DialogController`. However, this is poor design, imo.

```
public class DialogController {

    // Ugh. DialogController cannot be used outside the context where
    // MainController exists.
    private MainController mainController ;

    @FXML
    private Button okButton ;

    public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController ;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (mainController != null) {
                mainController.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private DialogController dialogController ;

    public void initialize() {
        dialogController.setMainController(this);
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```