# JavaFx TabPane : Want One Controller For 2 or more tab

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I'm new to java Fx. I have a TabPanel with 3 Tabs. Each Tab has many controls (text, buttons, etc.), and what I want is to assign a one controller for all Tab. The SceneBuilder only let me assign a controller for the whole view, I mean, only the top panel (the root) has the "Controller class" option, so How to write the code for all the tabs in one class.

i have .fxml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<Pane lns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  
 fx:controller="Application.LoginController">
    <children>   
 <TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight=" -
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
      <Tab text="Register">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" 
    prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="45.0" text="Name" />
                    <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="102.0" text="Password" 
/>
                    <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="151.0" text="City" />
                    <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="204.0" text="Email" />
                    <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="246.0" text="Phone" />
                    <TextField fx:id="name" 
 layoutX="164.0"layoutY="41.0"/>
                    <TextField fx:id="passwd" layoutX="164.0" 
  layoutY="98.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="city" layoutX="164.0" 
 layoutY="147.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="email" layoutX="164.0" 
 layoutY="200.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="phone" layoutX="164.0" 
 layoutY="242.0" />
                    <Button fx:id="register" layoutX="129.0" 
 layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Register" />
                    <Button fx:id="cancle" cancelButton="true" 
 layoutX="274.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancle" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="Login">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" 
    prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="57.0" text="User Name" 
 />
                    <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="103.0" text="Password" 
 />
                    <Button fx:id="myLogin" layoutX="145.0" 
  layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" />
                    <Button fx:id="cancle" cancelButton="true" 
 layoutX="274.0" layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancle" />
                    <TextField fx:id="uName" layoutX="145.0" 
 layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="205.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="pwd" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="99.0" 
 prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
 </Pane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple javafx controllers with different fxml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342259/how-to-create-multiple-javafx-controllers-with-different-fxml-files)

Comment: but i want a single controller for multiple tab in a single fxml

Comment: Your current controller can handle all tabs associated with it. There is no need to create different controllers for different tabs.

Comment: There should, in almost all cases, be a one-one correspondence between FXML files and Controller classes, and you can not split a single FXML over two controllers. So if you want one controller, use one FXML file. If you want a controller for the content of each tab, then you need to create a separate FXML file for the layout of each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app demonstrates how to use a controller to interact with different `Node`s in different `Tab`s in a `TabPane`.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication151 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{
    //Tab1 nodes
    @FXML private Label lblTab1;
    @FXML private TextField tfTab1;

    //Tab2 nodes
    @FXML private Label lblTab2;
    @FXML private TextField tfTab2;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        //This code set the Tab1 label's text to what is show in the TextField on Tab1
        tfTab1.setOnKeyReleased((event)->{
            lblTab1.setText(tfTab1.getText());
        });

        //This code set the Tab2 label's text to what is show in the TextField on Tab2
        tfTab2.setOnKeyReleased((event)->{
            lblTab2.setText(tfTab2.getText());
        });
    }    

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="588.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication151.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <TabPane layoutX="87.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="tfTab1" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="84.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="220.0" />
                        <StackPane layoutX="27.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="lblTab1" text="Label" />
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="tfTab2" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="86.0" />
                        <StackPane layoutX="195.0" layoutY="140.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="lblTab2" text="Label" />
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new `.fxml` file for the Tab then set the `fx:controller=TabController` then you can `<fx:include source="myTab.fxml">`
So you can include this 3 times then you will have three tabs with the sam controller.

So the main `.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<TabPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="TabPaneController">
    <tabs>
        <fx:include fx:id="FirstTab" source="CustomTab.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="SecondTab" source="CustomTab.fxml"/>
        <fx:include fx:id="ThirdTab" source="CustomTab.fxml"/>
    </tabs>
</TabPane
```

>

And the child `.fxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<Tab xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
     fx:controller="TabController">
<!--content-->
</Tab>
```

So now you have three tabs with the same `Controller`.

Comment: thanks @sunflame  i dnt want to include another .fxml i have a single .fxml file contains tab pane having 3 tabs but when i generating the TabController then it only contains controls of first(root) tab. so i want to add controls from 2nd and 3rd tab also.

Comment: I have edited my answer chek it if its the solution for you.